#  How to apply Update if an item exists and Insert otherwise

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

How to create a procedure that  goes from the top of the table and compares the value to null
  - If a match is found, insert an element in this position.
  - If not, the element is inserted into a new row

I need to correct a second row which contains null values in 4 last columns regardless of values in the Id and PropertyId columns

Here is a screenshot of my DB

[image]

Here is a samples of data:

[image]

Now it works so, which is not suitable to me, instead it should update the row with null values like on the last screenshot

[image]

But the next  entry should overwrite the value of NULL for Item, ItemId, InstanceId and Instance

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do? Why do you need a cursor?

Comment: Please give table structures, example data and explain what "manufacture of an element in this position" means? Sounds like something that doesn't need a cursor and can be done in a set based way (possibly using `Merge` for 2008)

Comment: @Martin Smith I have updated my question

Comment: @revolutionkpi: your update did not answer Martin's questions, though.

Comment: @revolutionkpi: So this is homework?

Comment: @leppie, no, I am trying to do this task with different ways

Comment: Could you then please give some more context ? I have a hard time figuring out why you'd want to do that operation in  that specific way.

Comment: I suggest thatwith this way the program will run faster

Comment: What is the source of information for the update? Where do you get the values from?

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson, the source of information for the update came from c# method

Comment: Ok. What fields determines if you should update or insert?

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson, it shoud check: if there is a null fild for example in Item, it should write the next item in first cell with null value in this column if there is not null item in this column it should insert valu on the next cell

Answer (score 1):

Write a stored procedure like:

```
create procedure INSERT_OR_UPDATE as
begin
  if exists ( select * from Numerations where <your condition> )
    begin
      update Numerations set < ... > where < ... >
    end
  else
    begin
      insert into Numerations values <...>
    end
end
```

You have to check the syntax because I cannot test my code right now.

Comment: @ Nicola Musatti, so for example for Property column it should be: create procedure INSERT_OR_UPDATE as
begin
  if exists ( select * from Numerations where Property=null )
    begin
      update Numerations set Property  where  Property=Property
    end
  else
    begin
      insert into Numerations values  @Property 
    end
end

Comment: The stored procedure in my example only executes one statement, either an insert or an update. If you need different statements for each row in your table you probably need to write a stored procedure that uses a cursor.

Comment: so, do you know how to write and can you help me with a stored procedure that uses a cursor?

Comment: or it can be realised with 3 different stored procedure?