# Check for the respective data in a specific column and if not detected, then insert. Otherwise update

Tags: mysql

I need to insert new row into table foo. But before insert those data, I need to check there was already inserted a row for the respective user name. If there has been already inserted, then I need to update the current data with the new data.

I know to do this using PHP if condition. But I love to do this using MySQL functions/statements by just a one line. Please can anyone help me?

For the example, kindly use the following statement. It should be updated.

```
$in = "insert into foo(username, text) values('user-x', 'user-x-text')";
Mysql_query($in);
```

When searching for similar questions, I got this post: [Similar question with an answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873373/how-to-apply-update-if-an-item-exists-and-insert-otherwise) But I was struggle to use that solution since I don't know, the process occur by that code snippet will get down the server resources like speed etc. Because this script will run about 20 times per user.

Thank you.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql

Comment: @talkol: Okay, is it use all the columns that indicated to detect there is being insert a duplicate one? I need to be it duplicate if only the username exist. But in my table, username is not a primary key and it is only an index key.

Comment: And it shouldn't get as a duplicate if the same text detected.

Comment: I think if username is UNIQUE, it doesn't have to be a primary key for on duplicate to work

Comment: also, take a look at the mysql-specific REPLACE INTO (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-replace.aspx)

Comment: @talkol replace into is the thing exactly I was looking for. I knew there should be a shortcut for this. Thanks talkol. I don't know how to rate up your comment. Anyway your comment was solved my problem.

Comment: I don't think REPLACE INTO is the best solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168928/what-are-practical-differences-between-replace-and-insert-on-duplicate-ke and http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replace-into-think-twice). I think you can make it work with ON DUPLICATE KEY, and then accept my answer ;)

Comment: Yes, you are right. According to liks that you passed, 'replace into' deletes the row completely. But I thought it will delete only mentioned column data in the statement. That is why I told my problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should be able to work

[Make username a `UNIQUE` index, it doesn't have to be a primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

If I'm not mistaken, DUPLICATE KEY will run only when you have a collision in any of the columns you supply that is either a primary key or unique index. In your case, text column is neither so it will be ignored for collisions.

`INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works on unique indexes as confirmed by the [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Okay, I can set that key to be unique. Then should I use where clause after the update values?
In future, I need to add more column to this table. Even after I add those, I still need to allow it to be duplicate if and only if the username is detected.

Comment: That's the code I had in mind: INSERT INTO foo (username,text) VALUES ('user-x','user-x-text') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE text='user-x-text';

Comment: You can add as many columns as you want and it will only look at username as long as in the list of columns in the statement: foo(username,text) the only column that is either primary key or unique is only username